# replacing flat-file db with proper database with record level editing

Tags: database, perl, flat-file

I cannot install SQLite on a remote machine, so I have to find a way to store a large amount of data in some kind of database structure.

Example data

```
key,values...
key,values....
..
```

There are currently about a million rows in a 20MB flat file, and hourly I have to read through each record and value in the file and update or add a record. Since it is a flat file I have to rewrite the whole file each time.

I am looking at the [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) module, but I think it also writes data sequentially. I want to edit only those records which need to be changed.

**reading and updating of random records is a requirement. Additions can be anywhere(order is not important)**

Can anyone suggest something? How will I know if I can setup a native Berkeley database file on these systems, which are a mixture of Solaris and Linux?

**________________finally__________________**

finally I understood things better (thank you all), and based on your suggestions I used AnyDBM_File. It found NDBM_File ('C' library) installed on all OS. So far so good.

Just to check how it will play out in real world. I ran a sample script to add `1 million records` (the max records i think i may ever get in a day, normally between 500k to 700k). OMG it created a **110G data file** on my disk !!!! and all the records were like:

```
a628234 = 0.178532683639599
```

I mean my real world records are longer than that. compare this to a flat file which is holding real-life 700k+ records and is only 15Mb on disk.

I am disappointed with the **slowness and bloat-ness** of this, so for now i think i will pay the price by writing the whole file each time an edit is required.

Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Does your flat file have a fixed record length, or is it comma-separated or similar?

Comment: record length is not fixed and that value changes, depending on program logic. Also if i use these various perl modules AnyDBM_File or DB_File. do i need a db server also, on my OS?

Comment: `perldoc perlport` has this to say about DBM: "There is no one DBM module available on all platforms. SDBM_File and the others are generally available on all Unix and DOSish ports, but not in MacPerl, where only NBDM_File and DB_File are available. The good news is that at least some DBM module should be available, and AnyDBM_File will use whichever module it can find. Of course, then the code needs to be fairly strict, dropping to the greatest common factor (e.g., not exceeding 1K for each record), so that it will work with any DBM module. See AnyDBM_File for more details."

Comment: And no, you do not need a database server to use DBM.

Comment: ThisSuitIsBlackNot, thank you. but is the documentation talking about perl modules _or_ db libraris installed in OS. in my situation i looked around and found: db.h on one server and dbm.h in another. So I am understanding that all these perl modules are just 'connectors' to the actual db libraries which are to be installed separately in the OS ? is that right?

Comment: db.h and dbm.h are C header files, not Perl modules. Install `AnyDBM_File` and the particular backend you want (`NDBM_File`, `DB_File`, etc.) using `cpan`, e.g. `cpan AnyDBM_File DB_File`

Comment: Also note that *some* DBM implementation will be available on any platform where you can build Perl, since the source for SDBM comes with Perl itself. SDBM is slower than the alternatives, though, so I'd only use it if nothing else is available.

Comment: "all these perl modules are just 'connectors' to the actual db libraries which are to be installed separately in the OS" Yes, although I think any *nix system will have some version of DBM installed by default (and as I said in my last comment, you should get SDBM anywhere you can build Perl).

Comment: very imp link, which clearifies things: http://rio.murmansk.ru/doc_/dbi/ch02_07.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they said in the comments you may use SDBM_File module. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;

use Fcntl;
use SDBM_File;

my $filename = "dbdb";

my %h;

tie %h, 'SDBM_File', $filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666
    or die "Error: $!\n";

# To run only one time to fill the dbdb file.
# Next time you may delete this line and
# the output will be the same "16,40".    
$h{$_} = $_ * 2 . "," . $_ * 5  for 1..100;

say $h{8};

untie %h;
```

Output: 16,40

Answer (score -1):

Depends, what your program logic needs, but one solution is to partition database, based on keys. So you can deal with many smaller files instead of one big file.